# how do you set up two microservices that communicate with each other, one being public and one private, using Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices

I think that you can configure this in the `-service.yaml`. For example I have a frontend and a backend. The frontend should be public and my backend should be private. So how do you set up two microservices that communicate with each other, one being public and one private, using Kubernetes?

frontend-service.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: frontend
  name: frontend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8081
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8081
  selector:
    app: frontend
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

backend-service.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: backend
  name: backend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: backend
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

What I tried

```sh
kubectl apply -f frontend-deploy.yaml
kubectl get pods
kubectl apply -f frontend-service.yaml
kubectl get service
```

```sh
kubectl apply -f backend-deploy.yaml
kubectl get pods
kubectl apply -f backend-service.yaml
kubectl get service
```

```sh
kubectl expose deployment frontend --type=LoadBalancer --name=frontend-service.yaml
```

Comment: Hi!  I think for your backend service you should specify type `ClusterIP` instead (default).  By specifying `LoadBalancer`, you're exposing the it externally via your cloud provider's LB.

If you want to hit up your backend service internally, just hit up *service.namespace.svc.cluster.local* using internal DNS (or in your case, *backend.default.svc.cluster.local*)

Comment: @GlenYu thank you very much. I really appreciate it. Can you explain why the `LoadBalancer` makes the difference between a public and private service?

Comment: So you have 3 types: ClusterIP, NodePort and LoadBalancer.  ClusterIP uses the CIDR that's internal to your cluster and hence the name.  NodePort exposes a high random port number on your k8s node that maps to your pod/container port (this is akin to how you would traditionally map a port from host to container with Docker).  And lastly is LoadBalancer, which is external and can route the traffic to either ClusterIP or NodePort -- with ClusterIP being the most private and hence preferred/recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [ClusterIP type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) for the private / internal services which will make your application only available within the cluster:

> - `ClusterIP`: Exposes the Service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster. This is the default  `ServiceType`

...and [LoadBalancer type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) for the public services which are designed to receive requests from the outside the cluster:

> - [`LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer): Exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider's load balancer.  `NodePort`  and  `ClusterIP`  Services, to which the external load balancer routes, are automatically created.

Example:

Let's say that I have created frontend and backend deployments - frontend on 8081 port and backend on 8080. Services yamls are similar to yours (I used LoadBalancer for the frontend, and ClusterIP for the backend). Fronted service is available at the 80 port, backend at the 8080:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: frontend
  name: frontend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8081
  selector:
    app: frontend
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: backend
  name: backend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: backend
  type: ClusterIP
```

Let's check the services:

```sh
$ kubectl get svc
NAME                                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)        AGE
backend                             ClusterIP      10.36.9.41     <none>           8080/TCP       19m
frontend                            LoadBalancer   10.36.4.172    xx.xxx.xxx.xxx   80:32126/TCP   19m
```

As can see, both services have ClusterIP (used for communication inside the cluster) and frontend service has a LoadBalancer with public IP.

Let's [exec into a pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/) and send request to the frontend and backend using just a service name:

```sh
root@my-nginx-deployment-5bbb68bb8f-jgvrk:/# curl backend:8080
"hello world backend"
root@my-nginx-deployment-5bbb68bb8f-jgvrk:/# curl frontend:80
"hello world frontend"
```

It's working properly, because the pod that I exec into is in the same namespace (default). For communication between different namespaces you [should use `<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local` or ClusterIP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-work-by-dns-name):

```
root@my-nginx-deployment-5bbb68bb8f-jgvrk:/# curl backend.default.svc.cluster.local:8080
"hello world backend"
root@my-nginx-deployment-5bbb68bb8f-jgvrk:/# curl 10.36.9.41:8080
"hello world backend"
```

This is how communication inside cluster works in Kubernetes

For requests outside the cluster use LoadBalancer IP (`EXTERNAL-IP` in the `kubectl get svc` command):

```sh
user@shell-outside-the-cluster:~$ curl xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
"hello world frontend"
```

Consider using [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) when you have multiple applications which you want to expose publicly.

Also check these:

- [Access Services Running on Clusters | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-services/)
- [Service | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)
- [Debug Services | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/)
- [DNS for Services and Pods | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)